# Android: How to parse JSON Array to string

Tags: java, android, json, string, parsing

The JSON file format I need to use looks like this

```
 [{"fName":"Bob","lName":"Smoe","info":"is tall"},{"fName":"Claire","lName":"Smoegan","info":"has a big forehead"}]
```

I have an object list of people that I add to a JSON array. The code looks like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < peopleList.size(); i++){
        try {
            jArray.put(peopleList.get(i));
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

The problem is, I need to convert it to a string to write to a file, but when I use "jArray.toString()" it returns

```
"["com.example.zach.projectFile.Person@21b854e0", "com.example.zach.projectFile.Person@21b854e0", "com.example.zach.projectFile.Person@21b85400"....]
```

How do I get this to return it in the format requested above?

Comment: First, that is not *parsing*. Parsing is the other way (string to json). Second, it depends on what `jArray` is.

Comment: jArray is the JSONArray

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not following the rules for `put()` on a `JSONArray`. The parameter is supposed to be:

> a JSONObject, JSONArray, String, Boolean, Integer, Long, Double, NULL, or null. May not be NaNs or infinities. Unsupported values are not permitted and will cause the array to be in an inconsistent state.

`com.example.zach.projectFile.Person` is none of these. What `JSONArray` is doing is calling `toString()` on your `Person` objects and using that as the value for the array.

Your choices are:

1. Implement something like `toJSONObject()` on `Person`, which returns a `JSONObject` representation of the `Person` (e.g., a `JSONObject` that, when turned into JSON, results in something like `{"fName":"Bob","lName":"Smoe","info":"is tall"}`). Then, use `put(peopleList.get(i).toJSONObject()` to fill in the `JSONArray`.
2. Use something more sophisticated than the `org.json` classes, such as Gson.

Also, Andreas' note is correct. You are not parsing JSON. You are generating JSON. Parsing JSON would be converting a `String` containing JSON into `Person` objects.

Comment: I am having a strange problem. I did something similar while waiting for an answer (I used jsonObj.put("fName", fName);) but I am getting a problem where each time I put the object in the array using jArray.put(jsonObj), it fills the array with nothing but the last object enter. So if had 10 people, and the last one is "Clyde" then jArray has 10 entries, but they are all for Clyde. When I step through it adds all the object properties, but then overwrites the array on the jArray.put() method. Any suggestions?

Comment: @zachThePerson: Create new `JSONObject` instances per `Person`. It sounds like you are reusing the same one.

Comment: THANKS! I moved the "JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();" into the loop and it worked perfectly!